# How do I specify permissions for sbt artefacts

Tags: sbt, scala.js

How does one specify the permissions for files output by sbt? I need these to be set correctly in order to be able to test the code with my local Apache server.

In the scalaJS project after a clean `fastOptJS` I 
can see that the `launcherapp-fastopt.js` files are user read only.

```sh
$ ls -al target/scala-2.13/
total 240
drwxr-xr-x  6 hjs  staff    192 23 Oct 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 hjs  staff    160 23 Oct 11:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 hjs  staff    192 23 Oct 11:08 classes
-rw-------  1 hjs  staff  69861 23 Oct 11:08 launcherapp-fastopt.js
-rw-------  1 hjs  staff  48380 23 Oct 11:08 launcherapp-fastopt.js.map
drwxr-xr-x  3 hjs  staff     96 23 Oct 11:08 update
```

Apache won't see it with those permissions so I have to change the mode on the files like this:

```sh
$ chmod -R a+rX target/
$ ls -al target/scala-2.13/
total 240
drwxr-xr-x  6 hjs  staff    192 23 Oct 11:08 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 hjs  staff    160 23 Oct 11:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x  6 hjs  staff    192 23 Oct 11:08 classes
-rw-r--r--  1 hjs  staff  69861 23 Oct 11:08 launcherapp-fastopt.js
-rw-r--r--  1 hjs  staff  48380 23 Oct 11:08 launcherapp-fastopt.js.map
drwxr-xr-x  3 hjs  staff     96 23 Oct 11:08 update
```

Is there a way to specify the rights in sbt for the produced artefacts so I don't have to chmod everytime I compile?

For a use case see the [Launcher App](https://github.com/bblfish/LauncherApp)

Comment: This is (at this point in time) a known issue: https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js/issues/4212